# Why can't I make a connection with AzureDataSudio?

Tags: sql-server, linux, azure-data-studio, failed-to-connect

I am running SQL Server Linux container images with Docker on Debian Linux version 11.

I have connected successfully as 'root@sql1' from the command line with username 'SA':

[image]

I have downloaded AzureDataStudio, but can't make a connection:

[image]
[image]

**Note that I am using the same password.
I have entered the port '1433' under Advanced Settings, and this leads to the following error:**

[image]

**Thank you.**

Comment: My guess is you didn't map the SQL ports on the docker container. Since you run the `sqlcmd` inside the container and azure datastudio from outside the docker container

Comment: How exactly are you constructing your SQL Server container? Microsoft's images on Dockerhub are typically running the service using the `mssql` account, so getting a bash prompt with `root` is a little... concerning. When launching the container you'll need to publish (expose) an external port that's mapped to tcp/1433 inside the container.

Comment: All I can tell you is that I followed this tutorial from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-linux-2017&preserve-view=true&pivots=cs1-bash#pullandrun2017

Comment: Unless I am using `root`, the `sqlcmd` is not found.

Comment: `sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                       NAMES
d484caafccda   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/nonr…"   8 hours ago   Up 8 hours   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp, :::1433->1433/tcp   sql1`